# Si usa dire "una cosa un po' svampita"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Ho sentito a un'italiana dire "è una cosa un po' svampita" a proposito di questo brano del *Lessico famigliare* di Natalia Ginzburg, in cui la madre dell'autrice parla di una sua amica di infanzia, la Grassi:

> La guerra inghiottí anche il signor Polikar. Nemmeno della Grassi, che viveva a Friburgo, in Germania, si seppe piú nulla. Mia madre la evocava spesso. Diceva: 
>       – Chissà cosa farà in questo momento la Grassi? 
>       – Sarà morta! – a volte diceva. – Oh che senso che forse è morta la Grassi! 
>       La sua geografia era tutta sconvolta, dopo la guerra. Non si poteva piú evocare tranquillamente la Grassi e il signor Polikar.

Può darsi che io non abbia percepito del tutto bene quello che ha detto l'italiana menzionata perché non conoscevo questo aggettivo, "svampito". Infatti, me l'ho subito segnato per poter cercarlo dopo sul dizionario. Ma sono sicura che ha usato proprio "svampita" per riferirsi a questo passaggio.

Ho ricercato alla voce ["svampire" del vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/svampire) e anche al lemma ["svampito" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000598.jpg). Mi è sembrato però di capire che l'aggettivo "svampito" si usasse in senso figurato unicamente per qualificare una persona. È veramente così o si può invece anche dire "svampito" di una cosa come, per esempio, il discorso fatto da un personaggio?

Comment: La svampita sembra essere la madre, da quel poco che si può capire dal brano.

Comment: Concretamente (e classicamente) può essere svampito il profumo lasciato aperto. E possiamo anche parlare della tristezza svampita dopo la buona notizia, della prospettiva svampita al cambiare delle carte in gioco.
***Ma lo svampito dà il meglio di sé riferito alle  persone.*** https://unaparolaalgiorno.it/significato/svampito

Comment: Condivido che è molto strano usare “svampito” detto di una cosa (a meno che non sia appunto nell'uso raro e originario di “svaporato”), e in particolare non vedo che senso avrebbe detto di questo brano.

Comment: Capita che qualcuno, non conoscendo il significato di una parola, gliene assegni uno improprio in base al contesto in cui l'ha sentita e poi la adoperi a sproposito. Vedi *peritarsi*.

Answer (score 1):

Si può dire anche di una cosa, come un discorso. Ti riporto la definizione di svampito del dizionario Zingarelli.

> chi (o che) è distratto, svanito | una ragazza svampita, frivola,
> ostentatamente leggera

Comment: Non c'è contraddizione tra questa risposta e i commenti?

Comment: Io interpreto quella definizione come «chi è distratto o chi viene distratto». Non indica che «svampito» possa essere usato per cose.